# MySQL: Check entire column if any row has value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to switch conditionally if all rows are empty for `audio` column. I have tried with GROUP BY type but doesn't works.

```
  SELECT postid, title, has_audio, audio, type 
  FROM qa_posts 
  WHERE parentid=1
```

[image]

So if audio exist for entire column for that parent id that execute code A if not than code B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just `count` all rows for which `audio` is not `NULL`. But if your table is bigger and contains tons of rows etc. then the real problem with this approach is that such query this may be expensive for DB and at least be slower than it could be. Of course premature optimization is bad thing, but this is not the case - we are going to optimize the approach, not the code :)

> want to switch conditionally if all rows are empty for audio column

First, it would be good to think the question `are all rows' audio column empty?` it really the right one. And, no. It's not :) In fact you neither need to know `how many of rows are not null` nor `are all rows' audio column empty?` because it's **completely** irrelevant for your condition if there's 5, 10 or 100000's. What you should do is to "flip" the question and look for the answer to question like `if there's any row that is NOT null?`. And even both questions look similar at first glance, we are using database to get the answer, so this  actually is the whole game changer.

By logic, to answer the `if there's any row that is NOT null?` question it is just sufficient to find out if there **at least one** row with `audio` being `NOT NULL`. The "at least" thing allows us apply some constraints to the query, because `1` fulfills "at least one" condition nicely, we will use SQL `LIMIT 1`, which would make DB stop and return the result as soon as it finds first record matching the query, w/o need of going thru whole table. This simply should be faster, and less resource hungry.

Once executed, our query can return two results. Either we get nothing (zero rows returned), which means that all `audio`'s are `NULL` or, as opposite, we get something (single row, does not matter which one) which would mean the answer to `if there's any row that is NOT null?` question is 'yes, it is' (because at least the one returned is).

Comment: But in this image only 3 rows which could be 10 or 15 or more.. what in that case? I just only want to check if any audio field for the parent id is available. If any single field is not null than should return true. any suggestion?

Comment: Just narrow your select results to rows sharing your parent id with `WHERE parentid=1`

Comment: WebnetMobile is quite right.  Better answer than mine.  Best to attend to minimizing server load, even with small things like this, so that you're in the habit of it.

Comment: Oh I see! you mean I should check only NOT NULL with LIMIT 1 so if any row has value it will return true? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly, because you need to know "if all rows are empty for audio column" and not "how many rows are empty" (or not empty). And this approach will not hurt with many rows in DB (ensure you got index on your `audio` and `parentid` columns)

Comment: Cool I think I am getting it now. So to make my knowledge more clear last couple of queries. So it will return any one row which is not empty no matter either 3-6 has value, Correct? And what do you mean by `index` something this `$query['audio']`? or in query? here I have write query after your help `SELECT has_audio, audio, type FROM qa_posts WHERE parentid=$p_id AND audio IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1`

Comment: By index I mean database index: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index set on column to make lookups faster and more effective.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot for updating my knowledge and help. You all are amazing here.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do a select statement with a `select count(*)` for `WHERE audio != null`.  Then do a conditional statement based off the number you receive.  Make sure audio is indexed.

Comment: This is also nice idea.. you mean if count is > 0 than true.. right?

Comment: this is bad approach - i made a note in my answer why.

Comment: I see but I just want to check either any field has value or null only two condition and not actual count. so something like `if(audio == 0) { do nothing } else { do this }`

Answer (score 2):

You can simple check for `NOT NULL` rows like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND column <> ''
```